# My Hp 4520s webcam stops working every now and then

Tags: laptop, webcam

My HP notebook webcam stops working after some time, after I restart my system or it returns from sleep mode. It starts working again when i restart it.

So I think it isnt the driver issue because the webcam is shown in the imaging devices when the laptop is restarted. And when it fails to detect it disappears from the device manager as well.

Can anybody confirm what actually could the problem be, any even if it is a hardware issue any place where i can find videos to solve it or replace the part?

thanks

Comment: What version of windows are you running ?

Answer (score 0):

The webcam "driver" is Native for Windows 7, it is not provided by HP, Dell or any other PC maker, it is supplied by Microsoft and included in the OS at time of install.

You can manually re-install the webcam driver:

- Uninstall first:
  Use device manager to manually install the webcam driver, Open Device Manager, right click on the webcam device device and select "Uninstall"
- Re-install:
  Right click on any other piece of hardware and select "scan for hardware changes", Windows should re-install the driver.

More than likely the webcam is failing or the cable that connects it to the motherboard is.

Comment: yes i am also thinking it to be a hardware problem, because it works everytime I restart or resume the system from sleep, and it stops working after some time.

Comment: HP forums are full of inop webcam posts, they must use cheap ones.